# :edit in function does not opens path given in argument

Tags: vim

I have in .vimrc:

```
function! s:Edit(path)
    vsplit a:path
endfunction

command! -nargs=1  -complete=file E call s:Edit(<q-args>)
```

Problem is that in new window i have file named "a:path" not file passed as argument to :E command.

Although my function starts to work when i do:

```
exec "vsplit".a:path
```

Why?
Can it be done better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build up your command and execute it with `:execute`. e.g.

```
function! s:Edit(path)
    execute 'vsplit ' . a:path
endfunction

command! -nargs=1  -complete=file E call s:Edit(<q-args>)
```

For more help see `:h :exe`

#### Is there a better way?

Really depends on your goals. I would need more information about what this is supposed to do. However it seem like you want to create an alias for `:vsplit`. I would suggest you using [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) or a the very least the following:

```
command! -nargs=? -complete=file -bang E vsplit<bang> <args>
```

If all you are doing is trying to optimize key strokes then the following mapping would also be sufficient:

```
nnoremap <leader>v :vsp<space>
```

Personally I would just get used to using `:vsplit` and stop worrying.

Comment: This is what I did. Although, is there better way to do it?